# What is the quickest way to read a list of key/value pairs from xml into an Array or List

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an XML/ Xcode plist file.

```
<array>
<dict>
  <key>notes</key>
     <array>
        <string>C3</string>
        <string>C3</string>
        <string>D3♭</string>
        <string>F4</string>
     </array>
     <key>tuneName</key>
        <string>My Melody</string>
   </dict>
  <dict>
     <key>notes</key>
     <array>
        <string>C</string>
        <string>A</string>
        <string>G</string>
        <string>F4</string>
     </array>
     <key>tuneName</key>
        <string>My Other Melody</string>
   </dict>
</array>
```

In Objective-C it is as easy as `NSMutableArray *defaultData = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:pathToDefaultPlist] autorelease];`

and to save it:`[defaultData writeToFile:pathToDefaultPlist atomically:NO];`

This would automatically create a mutable array with dictionary sub objects whose objects can in turn be arrays.

Is there an easy way to do this in Java or do I have to parse the file my self? Further, what is the NSMutableDictionary equivalent type in Java?

Comment: May be you are looking for XPath?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can create hashes in a resource file, you can only create arrays.

The best way to do this then would be to create a string array resource whose values would need to be parsed when you load them.

E.g.

```
<string-array name="my_hash_hack">
   <item>"KEY1:VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3"</item>
   <item>"KEY2:VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3"</item>
</string-array>
```

I'm sure there are also other ways you could achieve the same thing but this gives you the general idea.